# Get all extension methods for type by use roslyn api

Tags: c#, methods, reflection, roslyn

I want get all extensions methods for type. For example for type `string` if I am use semanticmodel method lookupsymbols.

```
var sourceText = @"string a = "";
a."
var tree= CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(sourceTextx...);
....
var members = semanticModel.LookupSymbols(source.IndexOf("a."), someType, includeReducedExtensionMethods: true);
//this return all members with extension methods for type string someExtMethod(this string text)....


//I want get all extension with methods where first param might be one of them 
var interfaces = someType.AllInerfaces;
//for example IEnumerable<out T>, methods like: Select, Where, Aggregate...
```

Answer (score 2):

Call [`SemanticModel.LookupSymbols`](http://sourceroslyn.io/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis/Compilation/SemanticModel.cs,019112cdb218fa28) to get all valid symbols off of a container.

This is [how IntelliSense works](http://sourceroslyn.io/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Workspaces/Recommendations/CSharpRecommendationService.cs).

Comment: Thank you, but i can't understand without examples. Can i see some examples anywhere?

Comment: And is there a difference working with a CSharpScipt?